# Adding two files with decimal numbers discarding lines with non-numeric values

Tags: bash

Need to read two files that has a column each with decimal numbers and add them line by line into a third file. This I can do with bash and bc. 
Problem:
In some cases these two files may contain non-numeric values. When I come across non-numeric values I need to know it is not a number and skip the line even if one file has a valid number and then continue adding the remaining lines. Would like to do it in Bash itself.
Example below:

**file1**

```
1.1 
2.89
Nan
4.32
```

**file2**

```
2.1
2.1
42.6
1.1
```

**File3 (result file)**

```
3.2
4.99
5.42
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
paste -d+ file1 file2 | bc 2>/dev/null >file3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` and `paste` as:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '/^([0-9]+\.?|\.?)([0-9]*)*[ \t]+[0-9]+\.?([0-9]*)*$/ { print $1+$2 }' > File3
```

Comment: Only problem in this regex used in awk is, this will not accept if the line contains number, that _starts with_ a decimal point. It can accepts numbers containing (at most one) decimal point, but not at the start. Someone can suggest edit :-) EDIT: I found a solution. trying it.

Comment: Updated to take that as well.